# How to reproduce "Too Many open files" error in Shell

Tags: linux, shell, ulimit

Assume that my open file limit is 1024 per process,

Then how to reproduce `Too Many open file` error in shell script?

```
#!/bin/bash
a=0
while [ "$a" -lt 10 ]
do
   echo "Welcome $i times"
 a=`expr $a + 1`
   tail -f /dev/null > myfile$a &
done
```

I tried above, but it opens 10 files in 10 different processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ulimit -n` to set the maximum number of open files to a low number, and then open up more than that number of files using `exec` (Remember that file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 are already open at startup):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ulimit -n 5
exec 3</dev/null
exec 4</dev/null
exec 5</dev/null
exec 6</dev/null
```

Running this produces:

```
foo.sh: line 6: /dev/null: Too many open files
foo.sh: line 7: /dev/null: Too many open files
```

Comment: I guess you will run out of numeric file descriptors long before 1024, though.

Comment: @tripleee That's why you set it to a low number  to trigger it without having to open that many files (I assume this is for a test case for something)

Comment: Oh, definitely; I'm just saying if you really want to test with 1024 instead of an artificially low limit, you need a different approach. I'm not in a place where I can test, but I'm thinking you could redirect a shell builtin instead of `tail`, or perhaps nest a large number of `read` statements in a loop.